# Cannot convert datetime to string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database with some dates, i want to fetch them and convert them into a string[] to use in a graph.

```
        var Yaxis = db.Graphs
                    .Where(x => x.Node.Contains(Node))
                    .Select(x => x.Dates)
                    .ToArray();


        var data = new string[Yaxis.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < Yaxis.Length ; i++)
        {
            data[i] = Yaxis[i].ToString;
        }
```

The .ToString do not work here with a "non-delegate type"-error. I dont know any other way to parse the array to a string[].

Any idea?

Comment: ToString is not a delegate, "ToString()" is a method :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data[i] = Yaxis[i].ToString();
```

When you don't include the parentheses, the compiler will assume you're talking about the **function** `ToString`, when you're actually talking about the return value.

When you're talking about the function itself, it's called a delegate (kind of similar to a function pointer in C/C++), which explains the error you're getting.

Comment: @Habib No, it exactly addresses the problem. Look at the last three characters.

Comment: @Habib: No it's not - the brackets are missing in the question. That's the important bit, although Antonijn should include text explaining it.

Comment: @Habib, this answer contains parenthesis for the ToString() method.  So, the answer is correct ....

Comment: oh yes, my bad :) but you should have added the details as well +1

Comment: Thank you Antonijn, sometimes you stare yourself dumb on the code :)

Answer (score 2):

As Antonijn posted, the immediate problem is that you're using `ToString` without actually calling the method.

However, you can do better than this to start with by doing it in LINQ:

```
var data = db.Graphs
             .Where(x => x.Node.Contains(Node))
             .Select(x => x.Dates.ToString())
             .ToArray();
```

Note that we're calling `ToString()` in the projection here. If that doesn't give the result you want (e.g. because it performs the conversion in the database) you can split it into two `Select` calls, with an `AsEnumerable` call forcing the second one to execute locally:

```
var data = db.Graphs
             .Where(x => x.Node.Contains(Node))
             .Select(x => x.Dates)
             .AsEnumerable()
             .Select(x => x.ToString())
             .ToArray();
```

This will use the default string representation of `DateTime` in the current culture, of course. You may want to consider specifying a [standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) or [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) date/time format string to change the output format, and maybe even a different culture... it depends on what you're going to do with the data.

All of this assumes that you don't need `Yaxis` for anything else. If you *do* need `Yaxis`, you can still use LINQ to simplify your code:

```
var data = Yaxis.Select(x => x.ToString()).ToArray();
```